# How to add a ref using useRef in react for every element generated by array mapping and push the ref to an array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How do i add an ref in element in my example img using react useRef component? and pushing it to an collection array so i can manipulate every individual img style?

```jsx
import { useState, useRef } from "react";
import "./App.css";

function Carousell() {
  const imageRef = useRef(null);
  let collection = [];

  return (
    <div>
      {Array.from({ length: 6 }, (_, i) => {
        return (
          <img
            key={i}
            src={`./img/${i}.jpg`}
            alt="image"
            ref={imageRef}
            style={{
              position: "absolute",
              borderRadius: "5px",
              height: "200px",
            }}
          />
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Carousell;
```

Answer (score 1):

using function mode of ref

```js
 const refObj= useRef({});
    ...
     
     ref={r => { refObj.current[i] = r }}
```

Comment: With function mode we need to take care the case of `null`; `r` will be `null` when the component unmounts

Answer (score 0):

"you can create an array of refs and assign each img element a unique ref. This code is written by checking if the ref is not null before accessing its properties or methods."

```
   import React, { useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import "./App.css";

function Carousell() {
  const imageRefs = Array.from({ length: 6 }, () => useRef(null));

  useEffect(() => {
    // Now you can access individual refs in the imageRefs array
    console.log(imageRefs);

    // Example: Change the style of the first image if it exists
    const firstImageRef = imageRefs[0].current;
    if (firstImageRef) {
      firstImageRef.style.border = "2px solid red";
    }

    return () => {
      // Cleanup logic if needed (e.g., removing event listeners)
    };
  }, [imageRefs]);

  return (
    <div>
      {Array.from({ length: 6 }, (_, i) => (
        <img
          key={i}
          src={`./img/${i}.jpg`}
          alt="image"
          ref={imageRefs[i]}
          style={{
            position: "absolute",
            borderRadius: "5px",
            height: "200px",
          }}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Carousell;
```